Will the German Embassy in India accept a printed version of the Bundesagentur Fur Arbeit instead of the original document?
I am an Indian student travelling to Germany. My visa appointment is scheduled for next Friday, but my work permit documents (to apply for ZAV, at an institute in Jena) have been submitted today.
Does anyone know how long it will take for the ZAV permit to be processed? And will the Embassy accept a printout of the permit as received if I write a declaration saying that I will submit the original as soon as I receive it?
